# Can't launch eclipse from adt bundle in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, launch

So I downloaded the adt bundle for linux from developer.android.com extracted it, 32bit version, went to adt-bundle-linux-x86/eclipse tried to launch eclipse but it's giving me an error

> Could not display "/media/ACF3-BA90/adt-bundle-linux-x86/eclipse/eclipse".
>   There is no application installed for executable files. Do you want to search... blabla..

I'm pretty much new to linux and ubuntu... so can someone please help me fix this? :P

EDIT: The problem was caused because I had it extracted on removable media and Allow executing file as program (Properties -> Permissions) still didn't fix the problem, so I had to transfer it to my (static) Linux partition. That fixed the problem.

Comment: Why is it being launched from /media ?

Comment: well I extracted it on a free ntfs partition? is this causing the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I came across the same problem these days when i attempted to write cocos2d-x games with adt-bundle-linux. Now I finally fix that after googling around for hours.
It turns out that this has nothing to do with adt-bundle-linux. The truth is that linux security settings result in such situations. It disables any executable file from other sources (in this case, it comes from the Internet and linux regards it as dangerous and unreliable files).
Simply right click the eclipse and choose "properties", then go to the "Permission" tab and check "Allow executing file as program".
Hope this will help you.^_^

Comment: Still not opening for me..now when i open it, it does nothing. Neither any window nor a error message. Any idea what am I missing now

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have installed to some sort of removable media and therefore your install could have bad references for eclipse's files.

I would recommend you install Eclipse from Ubuntu's Software Manager and install the SDK from Eclipse's Plugin Manager.

Here's the tutorial for the SDK:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Cheers!